# Powershell Loop Check senario

Tags: powershell

Scenario - I'm trying to do a check for a file extension (mkv & mp4) and if these files are present within my download folder then it runs a series of functions which is present below (these are # for testing purposes but all work fine)

what I am trying to do is when it has completed one loop of this script, search again to see if any more mkv or mp4 files are present and run again and if they are not present stop.

```
$Files1 = "C:\Users\BRACEGIRDLE\Favorites\Desktop\MASTER_FOLDER\1_DOWNLOAD"

    If (Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include *.mkv,*.mp4 -Path $Files1)
      {Write-Host "MKV or MP4 File Exists"
            #MoveFilesFunction
            #RenameFilesFunction
            #MoveMoviesFunction
            #ConvertTVShowFunction
            #MetaDataFunction
      } Else {Write-Host "MKV or MP4 Does Not Exist"}
```

I think i need to use the Do While function, could someone confirm? 
if i was to use this then I don't know how id start the do.

script i have found to work through and learn is below

```
$a = 2
$max = 10

"enter the loop"
Do
    {
        If ($a -gt $max){break}

        "starting the loop"
        $a
        $a++

        If ($a -gt $max){break}

        "now '$a is $a"
    } While ($a -le $max)

"now do something outside the loop"
```

is this something i should be working with to some degree, obivously id need to taler and adapt to suit my needs but am i in the correct ball park to use this as a 'base' or do i need to use something else?

Many thanks!
Connor Bracegirdle

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, you have way over complicated this effort.

My suggestion is to us a simple forLoop.

```
$FileItems = Get-ChildItem  -Path 'F:\Music' -Recurse -Include *.mkv,*.mp4
ForEach($FileItem in $FileItems)
{ "MKV or MP4 File Exists for $($FileItem.Name)"
    #MoveFilesFunction
    #RenameFilesFunction
    #MoveMoviesFunction
    #ConvertTVShowFunction
    #MetaDataFunction
}
```

Since you are already only asking for the specific file types, this...

Else {Write-Host "MKV or MP4 Does Not Exist"}

...will never execute, it's not needed because of the use of your filter.
Write host is never needed unless you are color coding text or other custom formatting.

This...

Write-Host "MKV or MP4 Does Not Exist"

.. and this ..

"MKV or MP4 Does Not Exist"

… will, do the same thing. Send text to the screen, the other option is to use Write-Output vs what you have here.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, postanote.. but when you say ‘Else {write-host “mkv or mp4 does not exit”} ... will never execute, on my script is does when there isn’t a mkv or mp4 file in the folder? thanks for the hint on the. Write-host bit as well..

Will this for each function look for any additional mkv mp4 files after its already completed once then? As I want to check every time this operation is complete if there is any more content in the folder and then repeat until nothing is there

Thanks

Comment: @ConnorBracegirdle Provided you used an infinite `do while $True` loop it would constantly report `no file...` once present files are processed. Better schedule the script to run in intervals or use a file watcher.

Comment: This script is being activated by Bittorrent.. so when a file completes it runs this program to rename, convert, add metadata etc and move to appropriate folder.. but having issues with the metadata software running more than one application if 2 torrents complete nearly the same time it runs 2 metadata softwares. so I want it to check if any more files have completed and moved to the folder prior to closing down so it could reloop over if nessesary

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with this script but im having trouble getting the loop to break on a false reading of file content when it dissapears from the folder after a loop

```
$Files1 = "C:\Users\BRACEGIRDLE\Favorites\Desktop\MASTER_FOLDER\1_DOWNLOAD"
$SearchTrue = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include *.mkv,*.mp4 -Path $Files1

While ($SearchTrue)
     {  "MKV or MP4 File Exists"
        Start-Sleep 5
        #MoveFilesFunction
        #RenameFilesFunction
        #MoveMoviesFunction
        #ConvertTVShowFunction
        #MetaDataFunction 
        If ($SearchTrue -eq $null) {break}
     } 
 "MKV or MP4 Does Not Exist"
 Start-Sleep 5
```

what im doing is simulating the searched mkv or mp4 file been removed after its been moved due to the functions, but when i move the folder it still thinks the file is there and wont break the loop

thanks
connor bracegirdle

Comment: You once set the variable `$SearchTrue` with the content of a gci. The while condition doesn't change so it runs endless. Read `get-help about_while`

Comment: I understand the concept of the While function.. but i expected the Variable to still work none the less.. i have removed the "$SearchTrue" and putting the 'Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include *.mkv,*.mp4 -Path $Files1' into the While (Condition) seems to do the trick! thanks for the help LotPing
also trying to put the code format into the comment but i cant seem to get it to work

Answer (score 0):

To get the actual count of mkv/mp4 files, put the gci into the while condition (with the count property)

```
$Files1 = "C:\Users\BRACEGIRDLE\Favorites\Desktop\MASTER_FOLDER\1_DOWNLOAD"
While ((Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include *.mkv,*.mp4 -Path $Files1).Count -gt 0){
    "MKV or MP4 File Exists"
    #MoveFilesFunction
    #RenameFilesFunction
    #MoveMoviesFunction
    #ConvertTVShowFunction
    #MetaDataFunction 
} 
"MKV or MP4 Does Not Exist"
Start-Sleep 5
```